# Express performance requiring modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, express

Having a question regarding the performance of a NodeJS application.
When I have the following express app in `NodeJS`:

```
const app = require('express')();
const about = require('./about');

app.use('/about', about);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

My current understanding is that only when the server is started up it does need to `require()` these files using `commonJS` modules.

### Question:

Does the `express`  application has to execute the `require()` statements with every request to the server or is this only necessary when starting the server?

Any extra information about how express works under the hood would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those require are only run once when you start the app. It would be different if you include those in the router functions.

```
app.use('/about', (req, res) => {
  const some = require('some');
});
```

Still in this scenario, modules require are cached so it's not such a big deal.